# @Resource in Spring do not work?

Tags: java, spring

i am new with the Spring Framework and I tried the following example:

First I created two very simple classes

```
public class ObjectA {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am ObjectA";
    }
}

public class ObjectB {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am ObjectB";
    }
}
```

No I want to use this Classes managed by Spring.
So I made another Class which uses the @Resource (javax.annotation.Resource) Annotiation for wiring the two Objects.

```
public class MyApp {

    @Resource
    public ObjectA oa;

    @Resource
    public ObjectB ob;

    public void info() {
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println(oa);
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println(ob);
        System.out.println("--------------");

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mySpringConfig.xml");
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean( ObjectA.class ));
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean( ObjectB.class ));
        MyApp myApp = applicationContext.getBean( MyApp.class );
        myApp.info();
    }

}
```

The mySpringConfig.xml contains this:

```
[..]
<bean id="objectA" class="com.mySpringCompany.ObjectA" />
<bean id="objectb" class="com.mySpringCompany.ObjectB" />
<bean id="myApp" class="com.mySpringCompany.MyApp" />
[..]
```

Now when I run the Main-Method of MyApp I get the following:

```
I am ObjectA
I am ObjectB
--------------
null
--------------
null
--------------
```

So when I directly use applicationContext.getBean( ObjectA.class ) in the main-method I get an instance of ObjectA. When I want to get within the MyApp Object it doesn't work. But I think Spring should have injected the two Objects in the MyApp class. What does i made wrong? Thanks in advance for every help.

Comment: Did you write in your xml which package to scan? `<context:component-scan base-package="blah.blah.blah" />`

Comment: and I think in the class you should use `@Autowired` instead of `@Resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a good job defining all 3 beans in XML.

But you also need to activate configurations through annotations, else there is nothing to interpret `@Resource`. Spring does this only if you instruct it so.

This [Bean Post Processor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) handles `@Resource`.

You can simply define it as a bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Or you can use this:

```
<context:annotation-config>
```

Comment: That'd be `<context:annotation-config/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using applicationcontextas @Resource annotation is jdk based annotation so use configurableapplicationcontext.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).